# VBA SQL query saved as a string and loaded as logging back to the database with another query

Tags: excel, vba

```
query_executed = "SELECT p.FBN, p.Car_Number, p.Car_Title, p.Car_Type, p.Owner car_owner, p.open_closed as Car_Status, p.Car_Status as Status, p.Car_Date_Approved, p.date_submitted_for_approval, p.Expires_After as ""Car Expire"", " & _
                   "p.Site, p.Car_Lines, p.Capex, p.PO_Committed, p.PO_Invoiced, p.Cluster " & _
                   "FROM cobrarawdata.mcl_carline p " & _
                   "WHERE " & UserDefinedFilters & _
                   "AND (p.Capex > 0 OR p.PO_Committed > 0); "
```

I have that SQL query which is part of an excel vba used for reporting.

I have a request that we log all of the queries being executed.  So I am attempting the following:

```
#If Mac Then
    Sql = "INSERT INTO cobrarawdata.sssr_access_logging (username, event_datetime, event_type, query_executed) VALUES('" & LCase(Environ("USER")) & "','" & Format(Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "','CAR Balance Query','" & query_executed & "')"
    ExecuteSql (Sql)
#Else
    Sql = "INSERT INTO cobrarawdata.sssr_access_logging (username, event_datetime, event_type, query_executed) VALUES('" & LCase(Environ("Username")) & "','" & Format(Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "','CAR Balance Query','" & query_executed & "')"
    ExecuteSql (Sql)
#End If
```

I am receiving an error though when I try and use the query_executed in the insert query and I haven't been able to get any amount of jockeying with double quotes to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a potential work around.  In the query the filters all come through with ' in the string.  Removing those allows the concatenation, but it does not exactly represent the query.  Should be good enough.

```
Sql = "INSERT INTO cobrarawdata.sssr_access_logging (username, event_datetime, event_type, query_executed) VALUES('" & LCase(Environ("Username")) & "','" & Format(Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "','CAR Balance Query','" & Replace(query_executed, "'", "") & "')"
```